# ¿Cómo crear una función acumulador para una matriz en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, funcion

En JavaScript tengo algunas matrices como estas: `[1, '2', 3]` y `[[25], 50, ['75', [['50']]]]`. Estas matrices pueden contener sub matrices, números y cadenas.

Intento crear una *función acumulador* que debería ser capaz de iterar sobre estas matrices, efectuar una operación de suma, resta, multiplicación o división sobre las mismas y devolver un número con el resultado.

Esta es mi función:

```
Array.prototype.aggregate = function(array, op)
{
    let result = 0;

    array.forEach(item =>
    {
         switch (op)
         {
             case '+': result += item;
             case '-': result -= item;
             case '*': result *= item;
             case '/': result /= item;
         }
    });

    return result;
};
```

Y la invoco de esta forma:

```
console.log( [].aggregate([1, 2, 3], '+') );                    // Error: Me devuelve cero
console.log( [].aggregate([1, 2, 3], '*') );                    // Error: Me devuelve cero
console.log( [].aggregate([[25], 50, ['75', [['50']]]], '+') ); // Error: Me devuelve NaN
```

Pero siempre obtengo cero y NaN como valor devuelto, por lo que asumí que la razón era que no entraba al case, e hice la siguiente prueba con la matriz `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
case '+': result += item; console.log(item);
```

Que me muestra `1` `2` y `3` en consola, por lo que no entiendo porqué no se suman estos valoress a mi variable `result`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Particularmente, desaconsejo el extender los `prototype` de los tipos base de JavaScript (u otro lenguaje de programación que lo permita) a menos que sea realmente necesario, ya que esto puede introducir agujeros de seguridad, inconvenientes con librerías de terceros o incoherencias.

En su lugar, puedes optar por una función como esta: `function aggregateArray(array, op)`.

También aconsejo siempre tener en cuenta finalizar los `case` con `break`, que si no, se evalúan todos los casos, generando resultados incoherentes como este. Sin embargo, terminar cada caso con `break` solo resolverá el problema de forma superficial para las operaciones de suma y resta.

Considera el siguiente caso:

```
console.log( [].aggregate([0, 1, 2, 3], '*') ); // Error: Devuelve cero
console.log( [].aggregate([0, 1, 2, 3], '/') ); // Error: Devuelve Nan
```

El problema principal aquí es que incializas `result` a cero, en vez inicializarlo con el primer elemento de la matriz. Esa es la base de un acumulador como el que intentas conseguir, pero todavía queda un problema más.

Si tienes una matriz como esta: `[[1], 2]` y la evalúas con tu función, por ejemplo, con la operación de suma, equivaldría a algo como `[1] + 2` que es una instrucción inválida, ya que no puedes sumar una matriz con un número.

---

Lo primero sería *aplanar la matriz de origen*, esto es, combinar todas las sub matrices en una matriz simple, convirtiendo algo como `[[25], 50, ['75', [['50']]]]` en `[25, 50, '75', '50']`.

En [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) de SO se muestran algunas formas de lograr esto con JS, pero para este caso  haré uso de [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Esta función recibe un parámetro que indica el nivel de aplanamiento que se aplicará a la matriz, y como quiero que se aplane toda la matriz le pasaré [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

Sería algo así:

```
// arr es [[25], 50, ['75', [['50']]]]
// copyArray es  [ 25, 50, '75', '50']
let copyArray = array.flat(Infinity);
```

Acto seguido, puedes usar [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para efectuar las conversiones correspondientes a los elementos de la matriz resultante del aplanamiento.

En este caso me centraré solo en el tipo string:

```
let copyArray = array.flat(Infinity).map(item =>
{
    if (typeof item == 'string')
   {
        // En JS, convierte un valor numérico en forma de cadena a
        // su forma numérica mediante una operación de multiplicación
        // por uno
        return item * 1;
   }
   // Acá pueden colocarse más casos de conversión

   return item;
});
```

Y con esto, pasas de `[25, 50, '75', '50']` a `[25, 50, 75, 50]`. Ya tienes lo necesario para tu acumulador, recordando que la variable `result` debe empezar con el valor del primer elemento de la matriz y acto debes iterar sobre cada elemento de la matriz empezando desde el segundo, agregando el resultado de la operación entre el valor acumulado y el siguiente elemento de la matriz.

También podrías reemplazar tu `switch case` de cadena por un [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) como este: `(x, y) => x + y`.

```js
const aggregateArray = (arr, op) =>
{
    if (! Array.isArray(arr) || arr.length == 0 || typeof op != 'function')
    {
      return 0;
    }
  
    let copyArr = arr.flat(Infinity).map(item =>
    {
       if (typeof item == 'string')
       {
           // En JS, convierte un valor numérico en forma de cadena a
           // su forma numérica mediante una operación de multiplicación
           // por uno
           return item * 1;
       }
       // Acá se pueden agregar más casos de conversión
       
       return item;
    });
    
    let result = copyArr[0];
    
    for (let i = 1; i < copyArr.length; i++)
    {
       result = op(result, copyArr[i]); 
    }
  
    return result;
};

// Pruebas
let array = [[25], 50, ['75', [['50']]]];

console.log('Suma: '           + aggregateArray(array, (x, y) => x + y));
console.log('Resta: '          + aggregateArray(array, (x, y) => x - y));
console.log('Multiplicación: ' + aggregateArray(array, (x, y) => x * y));
console.log('División: '       + aggregateArray(array, (x, y) => x / y));
```